# UIBarButtonItem with custom view fill toolbar evenly

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to add 6 `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view (`UIButton`) and I want each button to fill the height and be the same width as the other buttons while filling out the toolbar. With the following code, I got close, but theres a space at the beginning and the end of the toolbar. What am I doing wrong?  Removing the first and last spacer makes the space at the beginning and the end even larger, and removing all the spacers has huge gaps between each `UIBarButtonItem`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let b1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: one)
    let b2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: two)
    let b3 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: three)
    let b4 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: four)
    let b5 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: five)
    let b6 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: six)

    toolbarButtons = [spacer, b1, spacer, b2, spacer, b3, spacer, b4, spacer, b5, spacer, b6, spacer]

    setToolbarItems(toolbarButtons, animated: false)
}

private func createBottomButton(number: String) -> UIButton {
    let bottomButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    bottomButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 6, height: 44)
    bottomButton.setTitle(number, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    return bottomButton
}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't used tab bars often, but from what I remember, this is a non issue. Simply adding the barbuttonitems to the bar will center/spread them evenly, right?